# How to crop image in HTML as a percentage of it's height?

Tags: html, css, image

In my HTML code, I have a PNG image that I resized using CSS:

```
.adjust-image {
    border:1px solid #021a40;
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 1000px;
}

.img-container {
    position: relative;
}

    <div class= "img-container">
        <img class = "adjust-image noselect fade-out" src="{{ s.photo.url }}">
    </div>
```

Using the image's current size (with `max-height`), how can I crop the image as a percentage, instead of using `px` for height?

For instance, how can I get CSS written so that I can just designate something like: `height: 34%`?

Answer (score 0):

The height property can only use a percentage if its parent has a fixed height. What you can do however is place the image as a background image. Then you can set the height to 0, and as long as the width of the image is 100%, then you can use padding-bottom of a percentage since that references the width of its parent. Weird I know. So an example:

```
.img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 34%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Of course, this may not be the best semantically, but it is a classic way to use aspect ratio in CSS. And once [aspect-ratio](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/aspect-ratio/) is sufficiently supported, that will be a great option.